# ValidateSet and Switch Parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell function with two switch parameters. The switches cannot be used together, just one of the two.

There is any way to validate this scenario and prevent both being used together?

Comment: It sounds as though you'll need to use parameter sets. Scroll down to ParameterSetName Argument here and take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `ParameterSet`.

```
Param (
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Switch1")]
    [System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch]
    $Switch1,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Switch2")]
    [Switch]
    $Switch2
)
```

In this example, you cannot use `Switch1` and `Switch2` at the same time. If you need another paramter that can be used with both parameter sets:

```
Param (
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Switch1")]
    [Switch]
    $Switch1,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Switch2")]
    [Switch]
    $Switch2, 
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Switch1")]
    [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Switch2")]
    [string]
    $Parameter        
)
```

See also [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6)